Serving MMCV/MMDet on Databricks - GLIBC_2.32 not found
I'm trying to host MMDetection model on Databricks Serving (on Azure). The model is trained on 15.4 LTS ML. However, during the serving endpoint update, it complains about GLIBC_2.32:
An error occurred while loading the model: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mmcv/_ext.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)

Normally I'd just run apt-get install glibc or something on a startup script. However, Databricks documentation says Init scripts are not supported.
Question
So, how to get past this error and deploy an MMDet model on Databrciks?
Previously I deployed many PyTorch Lightning models (that is, no OpenMMLab) and glibc was not an issue for Databricks Serving.
Solution sketches
I see two possible paths towards potential solution.

Maybe there's a magic trick allowing installing missing libraries on the serving endpoint?
Alternatively, maybe we can get rid of the root cause of the problem, which is mmcv, and this error sounds a bit like opencv issue to me? The model I'm trying to use is CoDETR with a config based on this one.

Both sounds equally unlikely to me. Maybe there's another way?
Excerpt of key packages used:
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install uv
uv pip install torch==2.1.0 torchvision==0.16.0 numpy==1.26.4 openmim "mmengine==0.10.5"
uv pip install "mmcv==2.1.0" -f https://download.openmmlab.com/mmcv/dist/cu121/torch2.1.0/index.html
uv pip install albumentations==1.4.18 pycocotools==2.0.7 mlflow python-snappy==0.7.3
uv pip install lightning==2.2.2 mmdet==3.3.0

Full stack trace:
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]   File "/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mlflowserving/scoring_server/__init__.py", line 130, in _load_model_closure
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]     model = load_model_fn(path)
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]   File "/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mlflow/tracing/provider.py", line 309, in wrapper
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]     is_func_called, result = True, f(*args, **kwargs)
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]   File "/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mlflow/pyfunc/__init__.py", line 1067, in load_model
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]     model_impl = importlib.import_module(conf[MAIN])._load_pyfunc(data_path)
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]   File "/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mlflow/pyfunc/model.py", line 561, in _load_pyfunc
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]     context, python_model, signature = _load_context_model_and_signature(model_path, model_config)
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]   File "/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mlflow/pyfunc/model.py", line 555, in _load_context_model_and_signature
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]     python_model.load_context(context=context)
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]   File "/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/computer_vision/engine/mmdet/utils.py", line 44, in load_context
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]     from mmdet.apis import DetInferencer
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]   File "/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mmdet/apis/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]     from .det_inferencer import DetInferencer
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]   File "/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mmdet/apis/det_inferencer.py", line 22, in <module>
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]     from mmdet.evaluation import INSTANCE_OFFSET
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]   File "/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mmdet/evaluation/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]     from .metrics import *  # noqa: F401,F403
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]   File "/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mmdet/evaluation/metrics/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]     from .coco_metric import CocoMetric
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]   File "/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mmdet/evaluation/metrics/coco_metric.py", line 16, in <module>
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]     from mmdet.datasets.api_wrappers import COCO, COCOeval, COCOevalMP
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]   File "/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mmdet/datasets/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]     from .utils import get_loading_pipeline
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]   File "/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mmdet/datasets/utils.py", line 5, in <module>
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]     from mmdet.datasets.transforms import LoadAnnotations, LoadPanopticAnnotations
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]   File "/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mmdet/datasets/transforms/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]     from .formatting import (ImageToTensor, PackDetInputs, PackReIDInputs,
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]   File "/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mmdet/datasets/transforms/formatting.py", line 11, in <module>
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]     from mmdet.structures.bbox import BaseBoxes
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]   File "/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mmdet/structures/bbox/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]     from .base_boxes import BaseBoxes
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]   File "/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mmdet/structures/bbox/base_boxes.py", line 9, in <module>
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]     from mmdet.structures.mask.structures import BitmapMasks, PolygonMasks
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]   File "/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mmdet/structures/mask/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]     from .structures import (BaseInstanceMasks, BitmapMasks, PolygonMasks,
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]   File "/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mmdet/structures/mask/structures.py", line 12, in <module>
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]     from mmcv.ops.roi_align import roi_align
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]   File "/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mmcv/ops/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]     from .active_rotated_filter import active_rotated_filter
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]   File "/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mmcv/ops/active_rotated_filter.py", line 10, in <module>
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]     ext_module = ext_loader.load_ext(
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]   File "/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mmcv/utils/ext_loader.py", line 13, in load_ext
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]     ext = importlib.import_module('mmcv.' + name)
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]   File "/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000] ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mmcv/_ext.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:06 +0000] [595] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 595)
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:07 +0000] An error occurred while loading the model: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mmcv/_ext.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:07 +0000] Traceback (most recent call last):
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:07 +0000]   File "/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mlflowserving/scoring_server/__init__.py", line 212, in get_model_option_or_exit
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:07 +0000]     self.model = self.model_future.result()
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:07 +0000]                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:07 +0000]   File "/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.11/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 449, in result
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:07 +0000]     return self.__get_result()
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:07 +0000]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:07 +0000]   File "/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.11/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 401, in __get_result
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:07 +0000]     raise self._exception
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:07 +0000]   File "/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.11/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:07 +0000]     result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:07 +0000]              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:07 +0000]   File "/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mlflowserving/scoring_server/__init__.py", line 130, in _load_model_closure
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:07 +0000]     model = load_model_fn(path)
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:07 +0000]             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:07 +0000]   File "/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mlflow/tracing/provider.py", line 309, in wrapper
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:07 +0000]     is_func_called, result = True, f(*args, **kwargs)
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:07 +0000]                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:07 +0000]   File "/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mlflow/pyfunc/__init__.py", line 1067, in load_model
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:07 +0000]     model_impl = importlib.import_module(conf[MAIN])._load_pyfunc(data_path)
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:07 +0000]                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:07 +0000]   File "/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mlflow/pyfunc/model.py", line 561, in _load_pyfunc
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:07 +0000]     context, python_model, signature = _load_context_model_and_signature(model_path, model_config)
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:07 +0000]                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:07 +0000]   File "/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mlflow/pyfunc/model.py", line 555, in _load_context_model_and_signature
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:07 +0000]     python_model.load_context(context=context)
[mlrpj] [2024-12-30 09:50:07 +0000]   File "/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/computer_vision/engine/mmdet/utils.p


This is due to the incompatibility of the required glibc version in the runtime environment where the model is being deployed
one way is to use compatible prebuilt environment
Consider running your inference logic in a Databricks notebook and avoid using a serving endpoint. The notebook can include the correct glibc version and dependencies.

Add a bootstrap script to your cluster:
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get install -y python3.11
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libc/glibc-2.32.tar.gz
tar -xvzf glibc-2.32.tar.gz
cd glibc-2.32
mkdir build
cd build
../configure --prefix=/opt/glibc-2.32
make -j$(nproc)
sudo make install
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/glibc-2.32/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH


Use the cluster for development and ensure the required libraries are installed using pip or conda.


